# JavaScript select a portion of variables from object

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

here is by JS code:

```
var a = { depth: object_with_many_attributes.depth };
```

notice how *depth* appear twice, any standard way to rewrite by using *depth* just once?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object Destructuring, but in that case, you need to define additional variables, like in an example

```
const object_with_many_attributes = { depth: 'xxx', 'somethingOther': 'qwerty'};

const { depth, somethingOther } = object_with_many_attributes;

const a = { depth, somethingOther };
```

Answer (score 1):

If `depth` must be used only once, you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it with key:

```js
// assignment
var object_with_many_attributes = { depth: 'foo', bar: 123 };

// destructure it:
var { 'depth' : a } = object_with_many_attributes;

console.log('object a:', { a }); // use as object later
```